# Allocation of managed objects in Managed C++

Tags: c++, managed, allocation

Is it necessary to check for nullptr after allocating an object using gcnew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll get a [OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) in the object can't be allocated by the GC.